# Put result of awk into an array

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, awk, ksh

**When I run the following command on terminal,**

```
awk /984/ $files | awk -F, '{OFS=",";print $1,$4,$17}'
```

where,

```
files=`ls`
```

**I get this output:**

```
2013/08/18 12:51:37,11,724
2013/08/18 12:48:02,227,84769
```

I wish to create a script, run that command and assign the above result to an array in this way: (Separate lines as separate elements)

```
array[0] = 2013/08/18 12:51:37,11,724
array[1] = 2013/08/18 12:48:02,227,84769
```

BUT,

neither,

```
result=($(awk /string/ $files | awk -F, '{OFS=",";print $1,$4,$17}'))
```

nor,

```
result2=`awk /string/ $files | awk -F, '{OFS=",";print $1,$4,$17}'`
```

fulfills my purpose.

How to get an array like I specified?

Comment: You should use quotes like this `awk '/string/' "$files"` and change reading of files to `files=$(ls)`.  result2 is wrong, since it only evaluates the commands, needs outer `()` to store in array.

Comment: Adding quotes to `$files` may give wrong result, so ignore that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you say:

```
result=($(awk /string/ $files | awk -F, '{OFS=",";print $1,$4,$17}'))
```

the output would be split by whitespace.  Set `IFS` to a newline character, and you should see the desired result.  Say:

```
IFS=$'\n' result=($(awk /string/ $files | awk -F, '{OFS=",";print $1,$4,$17}'))
```

instead to capture different *lines* of output into an array.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is in the usage of () in your script.
I tried a similar example and got the required output

```
myarray=(`ls *.sh`)
for f in ${myarray[@]} 
do
    echo $f
done
```

I think the code of yours should be changed as follows

```
result=(`awk /string/ $files | awk -F, '{OFS=",";print $1,$4,$17}'`)
```

Comment: This is the same as: `result=($(awk /string/ $files | awk -F, '{OFS=",";print $1,$4,$17}'))` as he already posted, and you should try to avoid using the old back tics.

Answer (score 1):

To store variables in an array, output needs to be in a form like this:

```
result=$(one two "more data")
echo ${result[2]}
more data
```

Data separated by spaces. So tweak your output to give that format.

Can you give an example of what you get out of:

```
awk '/984/' $files | awk -F, '{OFS=",";print $1,$4,$17}'
```

It may be shorten to:

```
awk -F, '/984/ {OFS=",";print $1,$4,$17}' $files
```

Comment: The shortened command ran fine in terminal but when I did result=($(shortened_command)) in script and echoed result, it did not give any result.