# bash regex matches optional substring with group delimiters

Tags: regex, bash, substring

Basically I want to parse log entries with the following format:

> a1 b2 c3 )@in#( d4 e5 f6 )@out#( g7 h8 i9

1. `)@in#(` is the first delimiter between the previous two sub-strings (`a1 b2 c3` and `d4 e5 f6`).
2. `)@out#(` is an *optional* delimiter for `g7 h8 i9`.
3. There exist one or two spaces around the delimiter.

The interesting point is both the delimiters contain *multiple* characters.

I want to use get all sub-strings use Bash *regular expression*. This is my current code:

```sh
s1='a1 b2 c3 )@in#( d4 e5 f6 )@out#( g7 h8 i9'
s2='a1 b2 c3 )@in#( d4 e5 f6'

regex='^(.*)[[:space:]]+\)@in#\([[:space:]]+(.*)[[:space:]]+\)@out#\([[:space:]](.*)$'

[[ $s =~ $regex ]] && printf '%s\n%s\n%s\n%s\n' "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}" "${BASH_REMATCH[2]}" "${BASH_REMATCH[3]}
```

The code only matches s1 but **not** s2. This is why I write this post for your help.

BTW, can anyone clarify a bit on the difference between `[[:space:]]` and `\s`.

---

Update: from the comments and answers provided below, maybe Bash Regular Expression does not fit here. The `awk` is better then.

---

Instead of just printing the output, I want to capture them into variables or `read` them into an array for further process.

Comment: Try `regex='^(.*)[[:space:]]+\)@in#\([[:space:]]+([^@]*)([[:space:]]+\)@out#\([[:space:]]([^@]*))?$'` and then `[[ $s2 =~ $regex ]] && printf '%s\n%s\n%s\n%s\n' "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}" "${BASH_REMATCH[2]}" "${BASH_REMATCH[4]}"`. See https://ideone.com/8n2Dqn

Comment: You didn't make the `)@out#(...` part optional.

Comment: This really seems like a bad fit for Bash, and something you could do very easily e.g. in Awk.

Comment: A crucial difference is that Bash doesn't support `\s`.  This is popular in Perl and many regex dialects descended from or inspired by Perl's but the one in Bash is decidedly not one of those.

Comment: It seems that gnu bash supports `\s`.

Comment: @tripleee Could you give some hints about the `awk` method?

Comment: `awk '{ split(/\)@in#\(/, a); print "before: " a[1]; print "after: " a[2] }' file`

Comment: @revo I could find no support for this claim in the [reference manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html) or in my instance of Bash 3.2.57(1). Maybe it is supported in v4 or some particular release of v4.

Comment: @tripleee Right because I'm on v4.4.19.

Comment: No mention in https://github.com/samuelcolvin/bash/blob/master/CWRU/changelog but it only runs up through 4.2.

Comment: I couldn't find a ref either.

Comment: @tripleee just tried your method, it failed:

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew what is the ([^@]*) meaning? why not just (.*)?

Comment: @Zachary `(.*)?` is the same as `(.*)`, it matches too much if there are optional patterns after it. `[^@]*` does not match across `@` chars, it limits the `.`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew many thanks. I _thought_  the `@` is a reserved character of regular expression. so, it is not!

but i think this may be a bug? If the 2nd and 3rd sub-string contains a independent `@`, the regex won't match.

Comment: @Zachary No bug, it is expected. I do not think Bash regex can help here as it supports neither non-greedy quantifiers, nor lookaheads.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew have a look at: `a1 b2 c3 )@in#( d4 e5@ f6 )@out#( g7 h8 i9`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try Perl

```
$ echo "a1 b2 c3 )@in#( d4 e5 f6 )@out#( g7 h8 i9" | perl -lne ' @a=split(/\s*\)\@in#\(\s*|\s*\)\@out#\(\s*/); print join("\n",@a) '
a1 b2 c3
d4 e5 f6
g7 h8 i9

$ echo "a1 b2 c3 )@in#( d4 e5 f6 g7 h8 i9" | perl -lne ' @a=split(/\s*\)\@in#\(\s*|\s*\)\@out#\(\s*/); print join("\n",@a) '
a1 b2 c3
d4 e5 f6 g7 h8 i9

$
```

You can read the output by passing through a while loop

```
$ echo "a1 b2 c3 )@in#( d4 e5 f6 g7 h8 i9" | perl -lne ' @a=split(/\s*\)\@in#\(\s*|\s*\)\@out#\(\s*/); print join("\n",@a) ' | while read x;do; echo "val=$x"; done
val=a1 b2 c3
val=d4 e5 f6 g7 h8 i9
$
```

or print each arr value in perl and read them one-by-one

```
$ echo "a1 b2 c3 )@in#( d4 e5 f6 g7 h8 i9" | perl -lne ' @a=split(/\s*\)\@in#\(\s*|\s*\)\@out#\(\s*/); print $a[0] ' | read x1
$ echo $x1
a1 b2 c3
$

$ echo "a1 b2 c3 )@in#( d4 e5 f6 g7 h8 i9" | perl -lne ' @a=split(/\s*\)\@in#\(\s*|\s*\)\@out#\(\s*/); print $a[1] ' | read x2
$ echo $x2
d4 e5 f6 g7 h8 i9
$
```

Comment: How could I assign the matched fields to different variables or read them into an array for further process?

Comment: Yes, you can add them.. just edited my answer to include those..pls check

Comment: @Zachary..pls also consider upvoting the answer

Answer (score 0):

My final solution is as follows:

```sh
IFS=$'\n' _log_array=( $( awk -F'[[:space:]]*\\)@(in|out)#\\([[:space:]]*' '{ print NF; for (i = 1; i <= NF; ++i) print $i; }' <<< $s ) )
```

1. Set `IFS` to `\n`.
2. Instead of print to *stdout*, I assign the output to an *array*.
3. Note the extra parenthesis outside.

Here are two references:

1. https://stackoverflow.com/a/21130572/2336707
2. https://stackoverflow.com/a/42635720/2336707